# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue when I'm trying to load View

Tags: xcode, ios4

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *request=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://blablabla"];
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:request];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you need to send NSURL instead of NSString.

Try with

> NSURL *request = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blablabla"];

Comment: thanx but occurred warning Method '-parseXMLFileAtURL' not found return type defaults to (id); and when EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means that you are trying to access the object that already has been released